# Perl - Pushing Elements

Tags: arrays, perl, push

I have this loop where I populate a record and attempt to push it to an array:

```
while (@data = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
  $rec->{'article_id'}    = $data[0];
  $rec->{'category_id'}   = $data[1];
  $rec->{'category_name'} = $data[2];
  $rec->{'author_id'}     = $data[3];
  $rec->{'headline'}      = $data[4];
  $rec->{'teaser'}        = $data[5];
  $rec->{'author_name'}   = $data[7];

  push @article_data, $rec;
}
```

However, when this loop is done, @array_data only contains the last element which is in $rec.   I have printed $rec each time through the loop, and it is populated properly, with different values each time.    But, @array_data looks like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'author_name' => 'Equity Research',
          'author_id' => '631459560',
          'teaser' => 'Barnes' (B) first-quarter 2022 revenues increase 4% year over year.',
          'article_id' => '16608',
          'category_name' => 'Analyst Blog : Earnings Article',
          'category_id' => '298',
          'headline' => 'Barnes Group (B) Q1 Earnings & Revenues Surpass Estimates'
        };

$VAR2 = $VAR1;
$VAR3 = $VAR1;
$VAR4 = $VAR1;
```

This is the last element retrieved from the DB in the loop.   Why is it not pushing each item into a different element in @article_data?

Comment: You're pushing the same hashref into the array every time. Need a `my $rec;` at the start of the loop.

Comment: Always start your scripts with `use strict; use warnings;` (it might not have helped you fix this specific issue, but it's going to save you _a lot_ of time in the future).

Comment: Tip: When you want to dump an array or hash, I find it better to pass a reference to the array or hash to `Dumper` (`print( Dumper( \@article_data ) );` instead of `print( Dumper( @article_data ) );`).

Answer (score 2):

You only have one hash, and `$rec` is a reference to that hash. Each pass of the loop, you add a copy of that reference to the array. So you end up with multiple reference to the one hash.

But you want multiple hashes. One for each row. You can use `my %rec;` or `{}` to create

```perl
while ( my @data = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) {
   my %rec = ( 
      article_id    => $data[ 0 ],
      category_id   => $data[ 1 ],
      category_name => $data[ 2 ],
      author_id     => $data[ 3 ],
      headline      => $data[ 4 ],
      teaser        => $data[ 5 ],
      author_name   => $data[ 7 ],
   );

   push @article_data, \%rec;
}
```

or

```perl
while ( my @data = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) {
   push @article_data, {
      article_id    => $data[ 0 ],
      category_id   => $data[ 1 ],
      category_name => $data[ 2 ],
      author_id     => $data[ 3 ],
      headline      => $data[ 4 ],
      teaser        => $data[ 5 ],
      author_name   => $data[ 7 ],
   };
}
```

Comment: And the usual way to write this of course is to initialize directly with the values, as in
`my %rec = (
    article_id     => $data[0],
    category_id => $data[1],
...
);`

Comment: @Ecuador, yeah, I was tired. Updated.

Comment: On a side note, `$sth->fetchall_arrayref({})` would create this array of hashes in one line, provided you set the column names correctly in your SQL.

Comment: @AKHolland ...and provided you remove the 7th column from the query.

Answer (score 2):

You've already been given two working answers, I thought I would just elaborate around the various solutions.

```
while (@data = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
```

What you really should be doing here is using a lexically scoped loop variable, e.g. `my @data`. It is a widely used Perl idiom that prevents many headaches.

It is in the next row where your error occurs that this idiom would have saved you:

```
  $rec->{'article_id'}    = $data[0];
```

Since you did not create a lexical variable, these hash keys just get overwritten every loop iteration, much the same as if you had used a regular scalar variable:

```
  $article_id = $data[0];
```

However, a simple `my` declaration would have saved you all this grief:

```
my $rec;    # create a fresh variable
$rec->{'article_id'}    = $data[0];
```

But there is more. You are using a reference to a hash as a vehicle to put data into an array, but we don't really need that vehicle. Consider this:

```
push @article_data, {           # this creates a new anonymous hash ref
    article_id  => $data[0],    # you can insert comments here (*)
    category_id => $data[1],
    .... };                     # end of hash ref
```

We can just create the temporary hash ref on the fly with `{ ... }`. Everything inside those curly brackets will be considered hash key and value pairs.

This solution is appealing because it is verbose -- you can see everything very clearly, and you can even add comments (*) to the different values -- but sometimes you like it quick and neat. Especially if you have very large data structures. In which case you can use a hash slice. This will save you the effort of typing out the array indexes.

```
my @keys = qw(article_id category_id category_name author_id 
              headline teaser author_name);   # this can be place elsewhere in your code
my %rec;
@rec{ @keys } = @data;    # short and simple assignment
push @article_data, \%rec;
```

And if you absolutely prefer to use a hash ref, you can do

```
my $rec;
@{ $rec }{ @keys } = @data;
push @article_data, $rec;
```

Lastly, I feel sure that Perl [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) offers a feature where you can assign names to columns, or keep existing names as inherited from the database. For example [`fetchrow_hashref`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchrow_hashref). The `fetchall_arrayref` will fetch all the rows, and might do all this work for you with one single function call. Look it up.

Comment: Re "*This solution is appealing because it is verbose*", Your version isn't equivalent. You assign `$data[6]` to `author_name` instead of `$data[7]`.

Comment: `fetchrow_hashref` will use the name of the columns from the SQL statement, so using `fetchrow_hashref` might require changing the SQL statement. (And without changes to the SQL statement, the hashes will contain at least one extra field.)

Comment: @ikegami Well, maybe he *should* change the SQL statement. Depends on which is easier, perhaps. I did not notice that one array element was removed, but then again, this is not meant to be "ready to copy paste into production"-code, its just discussing alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

At the start of your loop, add `$rec = {};`.

Currently `$rec` remains the same entity throughout the loop, you only ever overwrite the values of a given set of keys  in each iteration. Therefore you end up with an array of identical copies.

Comment: `my %rec` would make more sense: there is no need for a reference here.

Comment: @Dada I think there is as you would want to push a reference on the target array.

Comment: @collapsar I believe Dada meant there's no reason to work with a reference. Effectively, they were suggesting what I did in my answer.

Comment: @ikegami Ok, I see.

Comment: What Ikegami said :) And then use `\%res` to take the reference at the end. But since that's what they did in their answer, maybe it can't hurt to have 2 different solutions :)

Comment: Also you can write `my $res = {};`, creating a new reference in each iteration

Comment: At first I thought this was wrong, but it does create a new reference, so it works. Maybe a testament to TIMTOWTDI. But I would still recommend using `my`, since it is a much more useful idiom. If you're doing a larger project, keeping track of when and where you should reset a variable will get tiresome and confusing.